# SQL Self join with closest time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have a table on a SQL Server with millions of lab results from different people (AA,BB etc.). Some substances, for instance sodium and potassium, may be measured by two different methods (A and B).

I would now like to do some sort of "self join" based on the following criteria:

I would like to compare the results of the same substance obtained 1) from the same person, 2) with the two different methods and 3) with the closest date/time stamp

For instance, each SampleID of Sodium_A analysis should be joined with the Sodium_B analysis from the same person with the closest date/time stamp:

Source table:

```
select T1.DateTime, T1.PersonID, T1.SampleID, A1.Analysis, T1.Result
from [DataTable] T1 LEFT JOIN
     [AnalysisTable] A1
     ON A1.DW_SK_Analyse = T1.DW_SK_Analyse
```

| DateTime | PersonID | SampleID | Analysis | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 10:30 | AA | 1 | Sodium_A | 10 |
| 01-01-2021 10:30 | AA | 1 | Potassium_A | 5 |
| 10-01-2021 11:30 | AA | 2 | Sodium_A | 15 |
| 10-01-2021 11:30 | AA | 2 | Potassium_A | 15 |
| 11-02-2021 12:30 | AA | 3 | Sodium_A | 20 |
| 16-03-2021 13:30 | AA | 4 | Sodium_A | 9 |
| 18-04-2021 14:30 | AA | 5 | Sodium_A | 1 |
| 02-01-2021 10:30 | AA | 6 | Sodium_B | 9 |
| 20-03-2021 13:30 | AA | 9 | Sodium_B | 11 |
| 20-04-2021 14:30 | AA | 10 | Sodium_B | 2 |
| 20-04-2021 14:30 | AA | 10 | Potassium_B | 6 |
| 23-05-2021 12:50 | BB | 13 | Sodium_B | 58 |
| 26-05-2021 11:20 | BB | 14 | Potassium_A | 11 |
| 29-05-2021 12:20 | BB | 15 | Sodium_A | 15 |
| 30-06-2021 11:20 | BB | 16 | Sodium_B | 24 |
| 30-06-2021 11:20 | BB | 16 | Potassium_B | 21 |

Desired result:

| DateTime1 | DateTime2 | PersonID | SampleID1 | SampleID2 | Analysis1 | Analysis2 | Result1 | Result2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 10:30 | 02-01-2021 10:30 | A | 1 | 6 | Sodium_A | Sodium_B | 10 | 9 |
| 10-01-2021 10:30 | 02-01-2021 10:30 | A | 2 | 6 | Sodium_A | Sodium_B | 15 | 9 |
| 29-05-2021 12:20 | 23-05-2021 12:50 | B | 15 | 13 | Sodium_A | Sodium_B | 15 | 58 |

I hope it makes sense... :-) Any idea on how to do this?

I've started with something like this, but it does not consider the time difference:

```
select 
T1.DateTime, T1.PersonID, T1.SampleID, A1.Analysis, T1.Result,
T2.DateTime, T2.PersonID, T2.SampleID, A2.Analysis, T2.Result 

from [DataTable] T1

LEFT JOIN  [AnalysisTable] A1  ON  A1.DW_SK_Analyse=T1.DW_SK_Analyse
INNER JOIN [DataTable] T2  ON  T1.PersonID=T2.PersonID
LEFT JOIN  [AnalysisTable] A2  ON  A2.DW_SK_Analyse=T2.DW_SK_Analyse

WHERE (select AnaType1  = 

CASE
WHEN   A1.Analysis='Sodium_A' THEN 'Sodium' 
WHEN   A1.Analysis='Potassium_A' THEN 'Potassium' 
else 'NN' end) = (select AnaType2  = 
CASE
WHEN   A2.Analysis='Sodium_B' THEN 'Sodium' 
WHEN   A2.Analysis='Potassium_B' THEN 'Potassium' 
else  'OO'
end )
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data for both involved tables and desired output. For now it looks like you can use OUTER APPLY-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
with t as (
      select T1.DateTime, T1.PersonID, T1.SampleID, A1.Analysis, T1.Result,
             left(A1.Analysis, len(A1.Analysis) - 2) as substance,
             right(A1.Analysis, 1) as which
      from [DataTable] T1 left join
           [AnalysisTable] A1
           on A1.DW_SK_Analyse = T1.DW_SK_Analyse
     )
select t.*, t_other.*
from t outer apply 
     (select top (1) t_other.*
      from t t_other
      where t_other.personId = t.personId and
            t_other.substance = t.substance and
            t_other.which <> t.which
      order by abs(datediff(second, t.datetime, t_other.datetime))
     ) t_other;
```

Note that I split the "analysis" into two parts, one for the substance and one for the particular test.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this approach, but the query runs forever, also when I'm only selecting a very limited time period in the "with t" clause.